# Can I limit user bandwidth/ram usage/CPU usage in Windows 2003/2008/2008 R2?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services, resources

I would like to limit the resource usage on a per user basis on a Windows Server 2003, 2008, or 2008 R2 machine. Suppose I have four users logged into one machine using TS and they are all using various resources. How do I make sure that each user gets his fair share?

Some examples of resources that I might want to limit are bandwidth (as-in speed), RAM usage, CPU usage, and bandwidth usage (as-in so many GB per month).

I know how to do this on Linux, but I am unfamiliar with Windows administration tools. I do not have access to anything upstream of the machine.

Answer (score 5):

You can try Windows System Resource Manager. I don't believe you can control bandwidth but you can control CPU and memory usage.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/wsrm/default.mspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771218(WS.10).aspx

Comment: +1 wsrm fits the use case perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

For complete bandwidth control you will most likely need to setup a proxy with authentication, and give separate login/password pairs to your users. This way you will control both speed and total traffic consumed per month.

Look for something like [Kerio](http://www.kerio.com/), [ISA](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/default.aspx), [Wingate](http://www.wingate.com/products/wingate/index.php), [3proxy](http://www.3proxy.ru/), [Freeproxy](http://www.handcraftedsoftware.org/index.php?page=4&action=category&cat_id=2). [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) could be capable of doing that, too.

Comment: On linux, I'd just force everything through squid. Is there a way to do this on windows without requiring manual authentication?

Comment: That I do not have specific experience with. If you use Active Directory, then squid is still the option: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/WindowsActiveDirectory . From what I've seen for FreeProxy and Sun Proxy, AD seems to be the only viable authentication option. Just found this one: http://www.softperfect.com/products/bandwidth/ , from the screenshots looks like the simplest tool which fits your requirements.

Comment: There is a somewhat related question here http://serverfault.com/questions/15429/squid-equivalent-for-windows